# Change From SQL to mongoid

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Can you help with this query?

```
SELECT nb_user, count(nb_user)  as nb_account FROM (
SELECT COUNT( USER.user_id ) AS nb_user
FROM USER
GROUP BY USER.account_id
) as toto
GROUP BY nb_user
```

I would like to translate it for use with mongoid on my rails 3.2 application.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This site is not for "gimme teh codez", you are expected to try to accomplish this yourself.

Comment: I tried to follow http://kylebanker.com/blog/2009/11/mongodb-advanced-grouping/ without result. I'm not able to count user_id by account_id

Answer (score 0):

I had a good result with this but i'm not sure it's the best solution.

In my controller:

```
map = {"sum" => 0}
reduce = "function(doc, prev) { 
if(prev[doc.user_user_id] == null){
prev[doc.user_user_id] = 1;
prev.sum += 1;
}
}"

data = MyLog.collection.group(:key =>'user_account_id', :initial => map, :reduce => reduce)

data_result = {}

data.each do |data|
if data_result[data['sum']].nil?
data_result[data['sum']] = 1
else
data_result[data['sum']] +=1
end
end
```